# how to use setInterval in getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, I'm trying to use setInterval inside of getDerivedStateFromProps, here is my code:

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, oldstate) {
        if (props.action === 'start') {
            timer = setInterval(() => {
                return {time: oldstate.time + 1}
            }, 1000)
        } else if (props.action === 'stop') {
            clearInterval(timer);
            props.addRecord(oldstate.time);
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
            return {time: 0}
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my scenario: in this component, I have a state {time: 0}, it's a count which will automatically increase by 1 per second when the props.action is 'start' and will stop increasing when the props.action is 'stop'. Should I use getDerivedStateFromProps? and this code has a bug, there is no meaning by returning a new state every second after the setInterval is invoked, and the state.time will not be increased, what should I do? Thx for your contribution!

Comment: You are trying to keep the state in `getDerivedStateFromProps` which is wrong, can you add few more codes

Comment: You're new to react... just don't use `getDerivedStateFromProps`... even after you gain more experience and think you need it, you still really don't. Just use the regular component lifecycle functions to handle updating state when props update.